# Javascript string equality

Tags: javascript

each element contains the same value.  When checked against this value by themselves, everything checks out.  But when compared against eachother, they are not shown as being equal.  help!  thanks!

```
time[x] == "2013-02-26 14:00:00"   ?
```

true

```
reference[x] == "2013-02-26 14:00:00"  ?
```

true

```
time[x] == reference[x]  ?
```

false

```
time[x].valueOf() == reference[x].valueOf()  ?
```

false

Comment: Can you include your full code?

Comment: have you tried just comparing strings? `time[x].toString() == reference[x].toString()`?

Comment: toString() is the way to go.  time[x].toString() == reference[x].toString() returns true, when those two values are the same.  Rock!  thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing you have two objects (and two objects are never equal). Maybe even two String objects, created with `new String("2013-02-26 14:00:00");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might happen because the two variables are of different types.

In case one of the variables holds a `Date` instance and the other a `String`, comparing both of them to a string literal will return true, while comparing their `valueOf()` results will return false, since `valueOf()` of a `Date` returns number of milliseconds since epoch, not the human-readable representation of a date (as opposed to `toString()`).

```
var a = new Date()
a.toString() //"Wed Feb 27 2013 01:41:51 GMT+0300 (MSK)"
a.valueOf()  //1361918511306

var b = "Wed Feb 27 2013 01:41:51 GMT+0300 (MSK)"
b.toString() //"Wed Feb 27 2013 01:41:51 GMT+0300 (MSK)"
b.valueOf()  //"Wed Feb 27 2013 01:41:51 GMT+0300 (MSK)"

a == "Wed Feb 27 2013 01:41:51 GMT+0300 (MSK)" //true
b == "Wed Feb 27 2013 01:41:51 GMT+0300 (MSK)" //true
a == b //true
a === b //false - types are being compared as well
a.valueOf() == b.valueOf() //false - 1361918511306 compared to "Wed Feb 27 2013 01:41:51 GMT+0300 (MSK)"
```