# string objects comparison always returning false

Tags: javascript

Here is the code that I am executing:

```
filterIssues: function(objectKey, text){
    var view = this;
    var keys = objectKey.split(".");
    var attributeKey = keys[0];
    var attributeName;
    if (keys.length > 1){
        attributeName = keys[1];
    }
    view.issues.each(function(issue){
        var value = issue.get(attributeKey);
        console.log(text);

        if (value === undefined || value === null){
            issue.trigger("hide");
            return;
        }

        if (attributeName !== undefined){
            value = value[attributeName];
        }

        if(value !== undefined){
            var matchedText = value.substring(0, text.length - 1);
            if ( matchedText === text){
                issue.trigger("show");
                console.log(value);  
                return;     
            }
        }
        issue.trigger("hide");
    });
}
```

The `matchedText == text` always returns `false`.

This is what I get when I play around with the console:

```
> matchedText
"sande"
> text
"sande"
> typeof(text)
"string"
> typeof(matchedText)
"string"
> matchedText === text
false
> matchedText == text
false
```

I do realize that and `===` will always check if both the objects are the same and I have read
[JavaScript equal operations anomalies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149676/javascript-equal-operations-anomalies) and [Javascript string equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15099599/javascript-string-equality).

Is there something wrong in the code that I am overlooking?

Comment: Check `matchedText.length` and `text.length`.

Comment: What sort of object is `issues` and what does `issues.each()` pass to the function (i.e. what is `issue`)? What does `issue.get()` return?

Comment: Maybe fence post error? `var matchedText = value.substring(0, text.length - 1);` did you try without - 1? what does `matchedText.valueOf() === text.valueOf()` or with (==) give you?

Comment: Did you checked with trim();

Comment: @James `matchedText.toString() == text.toString()` returns `false` and so does `===`

Comment: @FelixKling aaah... the length is different. I changed `text.length - 1` to `text.length` and still the same.

Comment: @RobG issues is a backbone model.

Comment: @Satyajit hmm just to be sure you could try `+ 1` (to rule out fence-post-error lol) but perhaps it's some crazy javascript quirk? What does `issue.trigger("hide")` do?

Comment: @James it triggers an event which will be caught by the backbone model. I have commented out the code and yet it has the same problem. It is just bonkers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I eventually found out what was the problem. Thanks for your responses and I believe you might not have come across the answer for the lack of information.

The problem lied in the `text` value that I was passing to the function. The `text` contained a `""` at the end and that's why comparison just did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misusing the `subString()` method. If you use `subString()`, use the length without -1.

Comment: I changed the length without -1 and still the same.

Comment: Using length-1 is definitely wrong. The substring must be the same length as the text for the caparison to be true, not 1 less.

Comment: Well I changed the code to use slice instead of substring. Still the same problem.